# Need help showing that $(\vec{b}-\vec{c})\cdot\vec{a} = 0$

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, vectors, physics

I am working on a vector question for my physics course and am having some trouble with part C.

The question reads,

"Let $\vec{a}$ = $\langle -1, 3, 0 \rangle$ and $\vec{b}$ = $\langle -1, 3, 6 \rangle$.

a) Find the scalar projection $l$ of $\vec{b}$ onto $\vec{a}$.

b) Find the vector $\vec{c}$ in the direction of $\vec{a}$ with length $l$.

c) Show that $(\vec{b}-\vec{c})\cdot\vec{a} = 0$. Explain why this must be the case for any vectors $\vec{a}$ and $\vec{b}$."

For parts a) and b), I got answers of $\sqrt{10}$ and $\langle -1, 3, 0 \rangle$ respectively. I was also able to prove that the equation was true for the given values of $\vec{a}$ and $\vec{b}$, but I have no clue as to where to start in proving that  $(\vec{b}-\vec{c})\cdot\vec{a} = 0$ for all vectors $\vec{a}$ and $\vec{b}$.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Hints: $l=\frac{\vec b\cdot\vec a}{\|\vec a\|}$ and $\vec c=\frac l{\|\vec a\|}\vec a.$

Comment: How is "projection" defined in this context, as the point with shortest distance?

Comment: @LutzLehmann https://flexbooks.ck12.org/cbook/ck-12-college-precalculus/section/9.6/primary/lesson/scalar-and-vector-projections-c-precalc/

Comment: So you have the definition as decomposition into parallel and perpendicular (or orthogonal) vectors. So if $b=b_\parallel+b_\perp$, and it turns out that $b_\parallel=a$, then of course $b-a=b_\perp$ is orthogonal to $a$.

Comment: Get a formula for $\vec{c}$ in terms of $\vec{a}$ and $\vec{b}$. Then compare $\vec{c} \cdot \vec{a}$ and $\vec{b} \cdot \vec{a}$